# Почему может возникать "ошибка в программе!" в Ardublock?

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide

Возникла необходимость обработать данные с помощью микроконтроллера. Приобрел ESP32 контроллер с чипом ch340C. Поставил драйвер, попытался залить простейшую программку для проверки(Использовал ArduBlock 3.0 как рекомендацию с коробки). Результат - на скриншоте. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным? Судя по содержанию данных в папке программы - логов она не ведет...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В Arduino IDE все работает корректно